# Cannot grep apt-cache show output

Tags: apt-cache

I have a list of packages and I want to know which packages are not available in the ubuntu repositories.

I type this command but it returns nothing :

```bash
$ apt-cache show vim TotO perl 2>&1 | grep "Unable to locate package"
$
```

It occurs in both Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS.

Can you help ?

Comment: What is the output of the apt-cache without grep ? Are there any "Unable to locate package" lines at all ?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202041/57134 .

Comment: @SorenA `N: Unable to locate package tOTo`

Comment: @WilliamMartens It's unrelated because my grep search pattern doesn't start by a `-`
The [N0rbert's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1281663/426176) works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per `apt-cache` [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html)

> `-q, --quiet`
> Quiet; produces output suitable for logging, omitting progress indicators. More `q`'s
> will produce more quietness up to a maximum of 2. You can also use `-q=#` to set the
> quietness level, overriding the configuration file. Configuration Item: `quiet`.

you have to pass `--quiet=0` to use `apt-cache` in scripts.

Use code below:

```
apt-cache --quiet=0 show vim TotO perl 2>&1 | grep "Unable to locate package"
```

or

```
apt-cache -q0 show vim TotO perl 2>&1 | grep "Unable to locate package"
```